# How to run Netbeans makefile on terminal

Tags: c++, netbeans, makefile

I am trying to run the netbeans makefile via my terminal of one of my C++ project

While executing

```
   Make
```

, I receive the following errors:

```
...
/bin/sh: 1: -o: not found
make[1]: *** [nbproject/qt-Debug.mk] Error 127
...
```

What should I do? Thanks in advance. Please note that I can easily build the program via Netbeans.

EDIT : I use ubuntu 13.04, netbeans 7.3, linux terminal.

Comment: Palteform ? Versions ? Compiler ?

Comment: @Golgauth Question edited. Sorry if I wasn't precise enough.

Answer (score 1):

I simply use:

```
make
```

or

```
make CONF=Release
```

in the project root (where the Makefile is located), and it works. I have a simple C++ project without anything extra.